# how to show message every time when record is deleted?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i have list of records with delete button. i am deleting record using ajax-Jquery .when i delete the record first time it shows message.but when i delete other record without refreshing page , it does not show message. for that , i need to refresh the page every time.

**jquery**

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="deleteRecord"]', function(){
     var id= $(this).attr('id');
     var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
         $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category",
                   data:{id:id},
                   cache: false,

                   success: function(data)
                   { 

                    if($.trim(data)== 'yes')
                    {  
                      $("#notice").html('<div class="alert alert-warning"<strong>Successfully !</strong> record deleted.</div>').fadeOut(5000);
                      parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});


                    }
                    else
                    {
                      alert('record can not be deleted.Try later. ');
                    }
                  }
             });
        }

 });
```

**html**

```
<div id="notice" >

     **here message is displayed**
</div>
```

message is shown first time , but second time message is not shown, i think when first time record is deleted , it removes the `div id=notice` . so second time function can not fount div element with id=notice.

Comment: Is item are getting delete second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd time , the `#notice` div is hidden so you are not showing it when you are displaying the error. Use `show` function on `#notice` div

```
   $("#notice")
   .show()
   .html('<div class="alert alert-warning"<strong>Successfully !</strong> record deleted.</div>')
   .fadeOut(5000);
```

Comment: **Note** : you are not removing the `div` with id `notice` , you are simply hiding it, which is what the `fadeOut` function does. 

More info http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 0):

please remove this `$(this).remove();` from

```
parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
```

and try